# Is the "or otherwise" here in this sentence correct or not?

Tags: word-usage

original sentence:

It is the contractor's responsibility to locate all trees adjacent to or otherwise affecting the works prior to the commencement of works.

clearly, the correct sentence should be:

It is the contractor's responsibility to locate all trees adjacent to prior to the commencement of works, otherwise they will affect the works.

I have two questions:

1. In the above sentence, can 'otherwise' be substituted by 'or otherwise'?
2. Can the complete "subject+verb+object" sentence after the 'otherwise' be simplified as a present participle phrase , i.e. Ving phrase?

Comment: You can't use _adjacent to_ on its own - it needs to be followed by _the works_.

Answer (score 1):

The original sentence is correct.

> It is the contractor's responsibility to locate all trees **adjacent to or otherwise affecting** the works prior to the commencement of works.

The highlighted words are a coordinated adjective phrase meaning
*adjacent to the works*
**or**
*otherwise affecting the works*.

Explaining further, it assumes that trees adjacent to the planned works will affect the works, but some trees that are not adjacent may still affect the works in another manner, that is, otherwise.

Neither of your questions can be answered because they apply to your ungrammatical substitute sentence.

Comment: I see, 'otherwise' here means similar as 'others', am I right?

Comment: In this use, it means "in another manner". So, trees may interfere by adjacency, or in another manner.

Comment: thanks a lot for your great help!